# How to remove spaces in wordpress stylesheet file style.css

Tags: html, css, wordpress

When I modified style.css file from wordpress editor I get spaces after each line these spaces increase the load time as well as its size. Here is the sample.

```css
input, 

textarea, 

button {

 outline:none!important;

 background:none;

 border-radius:0;

 box-shadow:0!important;

 -webkit-appearance: none!important;

}

* { 

 outline:none!important

}

::selection { 

 color:#ffffff; 

 opacity:1;

}
```

Please help me how I can remove those empty lines from style.css file.

Comment: I find it difficult to believe that whitespace such as that will impact on load times. Just google "CSS minify"

Comment: Are you using a plugin or is it just the standard WordPress editor? You may be able to check the php for the editor and keep this from happening in the future...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy it all to Sublime Text, then press ctrl+H (search and replace), and type

```
^\n
```

Check if the regular expression is on and replace all, this should remove all empty spaces, then just paste it back.

Comment: from where I can check regular expression?

Comment: There is a little icon in the left bottom corner looking like this: .*   click this

Answer (score 0):

You can install a minify plugin or

download the CSS file using a FTP Client like Filezilla,
optimize the css file,
upload & replace the CSS File.

Comment: is there any tool to optimize the css file, it hard to minify the css file manually because css file about 2000 lines of code.